# Returning default value from import statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, es6-promise

I'm trying to populate some data into an `Object` and I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong and why one approach works and the other does not. I'm guessing it has something to do with mutation or asynchronousity, but even so I can't figure out what exactly is the issue.

If you guys have any ideas, also maybe some reading materials and such, it would be really appreciated.

The data that's being proccesed:

```
  "flows": {
    "Flow-1": ["Slide-1", "Slide-1"],
    "Flow-2": ["Slide-1"],
    "Flow-3": ["Slide-1", "Slide-1"]
  }
```

`Slide-1` is a default export (a function) in a `JS` file. I am trying to import it using the `import statement` and add it to the `array`.
So `slideData` is the `return value` of the `import statement promise resolve`.

Approach #1:

```
for (i = 0; i < keysLen; i++) {
    data[keys[i]] = [];

    for(let a = 0; a < settings.flows[keys[i]].length; a++) {
        await import(`./Slides/${settings.flows[keys[i]][a]}/${settings.flows[keys[i]][a]}`).then(slideData => 
        data[keys[i]].push(slideData.default)).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

This loops through the above data, creates a **key/value** pair for each **flow**, imports the data through the `import statement` and pushes it into the formerly created `arrays`.

This approach works just fine but I feel like it can quickly become unreadable and even if it doesn't, I would still like to understand how we could implement `ES6 Array Methods` here, that being said, here is my attempt at this.

Approach #2:

```
keys.forEach(flow => data[flow] = settings.flows[flow].map(async slide => await import(`./Slides/${slide}/${slide}`).then(slideData => slideData.default).catch(err => console.log(err))));
```

What do I like here? The flexibility, you could format this to be a one liner, format it for readability or any preferred way and you could also change up or chain a lot of different things.

What's the problem then? Well, this approach seems to return the wrong values, check out this output:
[image]

It says that it resolved, I am returning the `default` property which I understand should contain the value of the completed `promise`, right? So why then does this `array` contain such data?

Comment: is `val.default` a promise or a value?

Comment: ```val.default``` is the returning value of the ```import``` promise, I will edit the question and change it to ```slideData.default``` for consistancy. Basically, the ```import statement``` imports a ```defatult.export``` of ```Slide-1```.

Comment: so, `.then(slideData => slideData.default).then(v => data[keys[i]].push(v))` if `val.default` is a promise (still not sure if you are saying it is or isn't a promise)

Comment: Sort of works, it generates double values. But to be honest I don't understand why it would, what we are doing is ```looping``` through the 3 flows inside of the ```object``` with the ```forEach method```, for each flow we are adding a key of ```data[flow]``` which is actually the the key name (Flow-1, Flow-2, Flow-3) into a ```objext``` and using the ```map method``` return a ```array``` as the value, that will contain an ```import``` for each name inside of the ```array```. Why would we need to first do an ```implicit return``` with ```slideData => slideData.default``` and then push it?

Comment: ```keys.forEach(flow => { data[flow] = []; settings.flows[flow].forEach(slide => import(`./Slides/${slide}/${slide}`).then(slideData => data[flow].push(slideData.default)).catch(err => console.log(err)));});``` This on the other hand does work. But its still not it should be if you ask me, because we are still first creating the ```key/value``` of ```key: Flow-1/2/3 - value: empty array``` and then pushing the imported values inside of the corresponding array. Why doesn't the ```map method``` work? Shouldn't it return an array with the specific values?